# How can I see the contents of a JavaScript Map using the node debugger?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, node-debugger

I am using the console debugger in NodeJS and want to watch a Map object. Here is the simple test script I want to practice on.

```
'use strict'

const data = new Map()

const readline = require('readline-sync')
let input
do {
  input = String(readline.question('enter command: ')).trim()
  debugger
  if (input.indexOf('add ') === 0) {
    const space = input.indexOf(' ')
    const item = input.substring(space).trim()
    console.log(`adding '${item}'`)
    let qty = 1
    debugger
    if (data.has(item)) qty = data.get(item) + 1
    data.set(item, qty)
  }
  if (input.indexOf('list') === 0) {
    data.forEach( (val, key) => {
        process.stdout.write(`${key}\t${val}\n`)
    })
  }
} while (input !== 'exit')
```

So I start the script in debug mode and attach a watcher to the `data` object.

```
node debug simpleDebug.js
< Debugger listening on 127.0.0.1:5858
connecting to 127.0.0.1:5858 ... ok
break in simpleDebug.js:2
  1 
> 2 'use strict'
  3 
  4 const data = new Map()
debug> watch('data')
debug> c
debug> enter command: add cheese
break in simpleDebug.js:10
Watchers:
  0: data = {"handle":15,"type":"map","text":"#<Map>"}

  8 do {
  9     input = String(readline.question('enter command: ')).trim()
>10     debugger
 11     if (input.indexOf('add ') === 0) {
 12         const space = input.indexOf(' ')
debug>
```

As you can see, the debugger does not show the values stored in the map. I assume these are part of the `"text"` key but how can I add a watcher to that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Relation_with_Array_objects) to transform a map into a 2D key-value Array

`watch('[...data]')`

Or if you want to watch a specific key's value

`watch("data.get('myKey')")`

or just the keys

`watch('[...data.keys()]')`

or just the values

`watch('[...data.values()]')`

Alternatively, you might consider using a regular object and watch that variable. Something like:

```
var obj = {};
//your code
if(obj[item]){
    obj[item] += 1;
} else {
    obj[item] = 1;
}
```

and
`watch('obj')`

Comment: Seriously such a life saver.  Thanks for this!!